# I Need Help in a Challenge

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles, area

My teacher challenged me with the question below:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2}\ast \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{41}}{1} \right )\ast \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{29}}{1} \right )\ast \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{10}}{1} \right )}$$

And I tried for a lot of time, but I stuck after doing things like 25 + 16 and 25+4, I don't even know if this is a way to solve this, if someone can do a step-by-step I would love, but do what you can and thanks already.

Sorry for the bad english

Comment: Hint: Compare this to Heron's formula for the area of a triangle.

Comment: One would think that a "challenge" is something for you to do yourself.

Comment: Computer algebra gives $17/2$... just so you can check your work.

Comment: You could clarify it for yourself by first using symbols. $a=\sqrt{41}$, $b=\sqrt{29}$, $c=\sqrt{10}$.  The expression simplifies to $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}$.  Work from here

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember you can accept an answer with the green tick mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simplify it bit by bit that is the easiest way!

First by combining and expanding using surd rules:

$$\frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2}\ast \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{41}}{1} \right )=\frac{\sqrt{290}-1}{2}$$

Then by combining the root $29$'s and $10$'s and expanding (FOIL):

$$ \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{29}}{1} \right )\ast \left ( \frac{\sqrt{41}+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{10}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{10}}{1} \right )=\sqrt{290}+\frac{1-\sqrt{290}}{2}$$

Then finally:

$$\frac{\sqrt{290}-1}{2} \ast \left (\sqrt{290}+\frac{1-\sqrt{290}}{2}\right)= \frac{289}{4} $$

And square root leaving you with $\frac{17}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

It seems the whole point of the challenge is to recognize the horrible expression
at hand is the area of a triangle computed using [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula).

Reall for any triangle with sides $a, b, c$, its area $\Delta$ is given by the formula:

$$\Delta = \frac14 \sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

Compare that to the horrible expression, one find it equals to
the area of a triangle with sides $a = \sqrt{41},b = \sqrt{29},c = \sqrt{10}$. 
Notice

$$41 = 4^2 + 5^2,\quad 29 = 5^2 + 2^2,\quad 10 = 1 + 3^2 = (4-5)^2 + (5-2)^2$$

We can realize such a triangle by placing the three vertices at

$$A : (5,2),\quad B : (4,5),\quad  C : (0,0)$$

The value we seek is simply

$$\frac12\left|\begin{matrix}5 & 2 & 1\\4 & 5 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right| = \frac12 (5\cdot 5 - 2\cdot 4) = \frac{17}{2}$$

Comment: I derived your formula for $\Delta$ but did not recognize it as Heron's formula.  Good insight (+1).

Comment: It’s even easier to recognize, I think, in the form $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s$ is the semi-perimeter $\frac12(a+b+c)$.